# HTML5, <textarea> according to a <select> value using just HTML5

Tags: html

I'm not sure but I think that you can change textarea value when a select option change just using HTML5. I can't find where I read about it. Someone of you could confirm this?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
  <html>
    <body>  
      <select>
        <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
        <option value="saab">Saab</option>
        <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
        <option value="audi">Audi</option>
      </select>
      <textarea>
        Can I change this text according to select option just using html5?
      </textarea>            
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: What do you mean by 'Just HTML5'. Are you using it in a buzzword sense and mean the triple HTML5/JS/CSS3? Or do you really mean HTML5 and nothing else?

Comment: I mean HTML and nothing else. HTML5 I supouse

Answer (score 3):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<p>Select a new car from the list.</p>

<select id="mySelect" onchange="myFunction()">
  <option value="Audi">Audi
  <option value="BMW">BMW
  <option value="Mercedes">Mercedes
  <option value="Volvo">Volvo
</select>

<textarea id="demo"></textarea>

<script>
function myFunction() {
    var x = document.getElementById("mySelect").value;
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = x;
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I think he is looking for only HTML5 solution.

Comment: That is. But I also appreciate this answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Just with HTML it is not possible. You can make that with a little code of javascript... and for easy-include [jquery](http://api.jquery.com/) like that:

```js
$(document).on('ready', function() {
  $('#select-model').on('change', function() {
    var value = $(this).val();
    $('#text-content').val(value);
  });
});
```

```css
/* Just to look good :) */
#text-content {
  width: 400px;
  height: 100px;
  padding: 5px;
}

#select-model {
  padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>

  <select id="select-model">
    <option value="">Select</option>
    <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
    <option value="saab">Saab</option>
    <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
    <option value="audi">Audi</option>
  </select>
  
  <br />

  <textarea id="text-content" placeholder="Can I change this text acording to select option just ussing html5?"></textarea>

</body>
</html>
```

Wish u good luck!

Comment: Thanks for your support  Boris

Comment: U welcome. Maybe not help u a lot but... clear HTML without javascript it is better, but for that situation it is not possible :/ However :) Long live and prosper :)